# Changing the name of location in embeded Google Maps information bubble

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am embedding a Google Maps in my site, but I would like to be able to change the name in the information bubble to a name other then 'Address' for an example I want to change the 'Address' in the information bubble in the following link so that it says 'Smart people work here'

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=One+Exchange+Plaza,+26th+Floor+New+York,+NY+10006&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=39.371738,86.572266&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1+Exchange+Plaza,+New+York,+10006&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=40.706793,-74.012592&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=One+Exchange+Plaza,+26th+Floor+New+York,+NY+10006&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=39.371738,86.572266&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1+Exchange+Plaza,+New+York,+10006&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=40.706793,-74.012592" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know [you have to build your own JavaScript page](http://jsfiddle.net/6qYJg/) to change that bubble. It only uses basic API components yet I think it's quite a hassle for a single marker. The advantage is that it's highly customizable. I simply tried to copy the original, leaving out the directions and search links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
      #infoContents { color: blue; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var spot = new google.maps.LatLng(40.706793,-74.012592);
      var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.712583,-74.00933592);
      var mapOptions = { center: mapCenter, zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
          "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/msmarker.shadow.png", 
          new google.maps.Size(59,32),
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          new google.maps.Point(15,32));

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: spot,
          icon: "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png",
          shadow: iconShadow
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<div id="infoContents"><b style="font-size: 16px">I am so Smart</b><br><br>1 Exchange Plaza<br>New York, NY 10006</div>'
        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 425px; height: 350px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My first attempt at mapping was using the Google Maps API v 3.0 but it would only accept long/lat coordinates, not address.  With my site, a user could input the address for a company, etc. And then later, a user could click on the company listing and see the details of the listing, including a map of the location.  I switched to this method when I realized I could just put the address into the URL to get the map of the location.  In your example, I would once again have to lookup the long/lat of the address.

Comment: You're right, you need geocoding to associate addresses to places with the API. I was only interested in changing the info bubble as was the original intent of the question. I don't know a way of doing that with the maps.google.com embedding.

Comment: I am sorry for not making it clear.  I wish the API accepted addresses instead of only long/lat

Comment: API does accept addresses, it's just an extra step you need. It's not terribly smart, for example, if you just write "100 Main St" it's unlikely you'll get what you want. Try the example geocoder https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple and explanation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResponses

Comment: No, I was inputting for an example: 123 1st street, Jacksonville, Florida, 32099, United States of America

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading this in 2016, you can create a map with Google MyMaps and save time ;)

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question.